# Comparing differences in characters in SQL (or AWS QuickSight)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

We are using Postgres and on our `student` table, we have columns for letter grades [A, B, C, D, F]. We have two columns for previous grade and the current grade. I'm trying to find a way to run a report on how much the grades have changed for each record. So essentially, I want a field for `current_grade-previous_grade` but since the values are text, I can't do that comparison easily. I was hoping that `parseInt` in AWS QuickSight will parse a value for the grades but [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parseInt-function.html) says it ignores non-numerical values. Since AWS QuickSight doesn't seem to solve this problem, how would I do this in my query in SQL when I don't have write access and can't create [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) for this? I was hoping for something simple like:

`SELECT id, report_card->'grade' as current_grade, report_card->'previous_grade' as old_grade, old_grade-current_grade FROM Students;`

Comment: If you have non-numerical values in grades, how do you plan on comparing them? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: They'll just be a letter grade like "A", "B","C","D" for each column. I just want to know the difference. Some languages would take the ASCII key for them and do a minus on them. For example, B-A would translate to 066-065 and result in 1. I'm thinking something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicksight seems to support `locate` which you might be able to tweak to your advantage. It's as if you're assigning numbers to grades in current_grade and previous_grade column

```
locate('ABCDEF', current_grade) - locate('ABCDEF', previous_grade)
```

If that doesn't work, they also have `ifelse`, which you could modify along these lines

```
ifelse(current_grade="A", 1, current_grade="B", 2, ......,current_grade="F", 6) - 
ifelse(previous_grade="A", 1, previous_grade="B", 2, ......,previous_grade="F", 6)
```

Comment: Thanks. ifelse was the best solution I could think of. It just felt a bit hacky but it does the job I think.

Comment: @Jorjani Did you try the one with locate?

Comment: Locate is an interesting idea. I'll try it.